# How to get the URL of a download link

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to parse a page which contains some links. These links, if followed, will redirect to some files to download.

For example, `<a href="http://example.com/file.php"> Download </a>` which redirects to `<a href="http://example.com/1.pdf"`.

I don't want to download the file, I just want to get the file link (int this case `http://example.com/1.pdf`).

I am trying this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, FALSE);     // Return in string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_exec($ch);
var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));
```

But, it gives me the file contents.

Does anyone have any idea how to this?

==EDIT==
Thank you guys. I solved it like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE);
curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
```

Now, `$info` contains the header and I can the link from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the output is being sent to the screen is because you're telling cURL to do so. If you want to store the response in a variable the following line:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, FALSE);`

should read:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);`

Then, actually retrieve the returned output from `curl_exec` like so:

`$output = curl_exec($ch);`

Once you have the returned HTML content from the remote page in the `$output` variable you can use [DOM<sup>*docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) or regex (**but preferably DOM**) to parse out any information you want.

**UPDATE**

I can't tell because the question is vaguely worded: is there actually a Location header redirect happening? If so, you'll want to do as @heiko suggests to prevent cURL from following the redirect and retrieve the headers. Then you can easily parse the contents of the location header:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER, TRUE); // add header output
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# make sure to not follow Location: Header
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, FALSE);
# add Response Header to Output, so that you can find the Location-Header in there!
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, TRUE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `RETURN TRANSFER as 1`, also use `htmlentities()` if you want to display HTML source on your page , else just `echo` the variable ( to display the page [redirects to google] ).

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.google.co.in";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);     // Return in string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$varx = curl_exec($ch);
echo htmlentities($varx);
?>
```

With the `$varx` variable , use **Regular Expressions** to match which data you want.